# Visualising rotations of a 3d object

Tags: abstract-algebra

In abstract algebra we are looking at the issue of orbits and stabilisers and applying this to colouring. 
I am extremely comfortable with the material except for visualising the various rotations of an object 
For example, looking at a cube,  I can just about visualise where the various edges  go to after a rotations by 90 degrees along an axis going through opposite faces. 
However I find it completely impossible to work out what the various edges are mapped to after rotation by 120 degrees along an axis going through opposite vertices. This is a big issue and I would be so grateful for any tips and idea.

Comment: Look at the cube along the rotation axis, it makes it much easier as the rotation becomes planar.

Comment: You might consider labeling up the faces  and vertices of an actual physical cube. While scissoring and gluing a [polyhedral net](http://www.korthalsaltes.com/pdf/cube.pdf) might seem a bit kindergarten, studying the result is not.

Comment: Alternatively, specifically for the cube example, it probably isn't so hard to get your hands on one without cutting one out. Other polyhedra, not so easy unless you have a dice set.

Comment: I am concerned about what I would do in an exam under time constraint.

Comment: Why do I find it so hard to visualise?